# Cannot uninstall Java

Tags: java

I am unable to uninstall the Java JRE from my system. I have used Windows Installer Cleanup but still the Java folder is in Program Files.

How can I remove Java from my PC? I'm using Windows Vista Home Premium.

Comment: I assume, that does not belong to stackoverflow (try superuser.com).

Comment: The Windows Installer CleanUp should have taken care of it, but it may not have removed the program directory itself. Are you sure the directory is not empty?

Comment: yes, still java folder is in my programfiles.

Answer (score 3):

From [here](http://support.microsoft.com/default.aspx?scid=kb;en-us;290301):

> Be aware that Windows Installer
>   CleanUp Utility will not remove the
>   actual program from your computer.
>   However, it will remove the
>   installation files so that you can
>   start the installation, upgrade, or
>   uninstall over.

Just delete the folder manually.

Answer (score 1):

**[Revo Uninstaller](http://www.revouninstaller.com/)** helps you to uninstall software and remove unwanted programs installed on your computer **even if you have problems uninstalling and cannot uninstall them from "Windows Add or Remove Programs" control panel applet**.

for a future reference: to avoid piling up tons of old java folders, don't auto-update. unistall the old version and then install the latest JRE manually, you can download the current **offline** installer [here](http://www.java.com/en/download/manual.jsp).